# How to reduce the activity dialog height in android

Tags: android

[image]

I am using an activity with style of **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"** .The activity is shown as dialog but the problem is to reduce the height of the dialog to specified level..

Please give me a solution??????

This is my activity dialog XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   style="@style/MyActionsDialogTheme">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Quick Actions"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:typeface="serif" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_edit"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Edit Reminder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Delete Reminder"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout code

Comment: @GrIsHu I just posted my layout code

Comment: do you want to hardcode it ?

Comment: If you are using custom style then give height to it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. give dialog main layout hight as `wrap_content`

if you give  `match_parent` means it'll fill the parent layout full so give `wrap_content`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_title"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Quick Actions"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_edit"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Edit Reminder"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Delete Reminder"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: @Android_kalai that backgroung image is the reason for that give small image for that or give any color and check..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
       style="@style/MyActionsDialogTheme">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_title"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Quick Actions"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edit"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Edit Reminder"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_delete"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Delete Reminder"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use wrap Content in place of matchparent in LinearLayout

Comment: then remove background image and try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the background image , then it's work